# How to Loop through Worksheets Except TOC

Tags: excel, vba

I’m trying to loop a Macro that will run through all worksheets, Except the "TOC" sheet.
    -Each worksheet will have a Table Created, formatted, and have formulas put in.

However, the macro tries to begin on the "TOC" sheet, which then causes an error.

I currently have:

```
Sub BrandRank_()

Dim wb As ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim TableName As String
Dim LstObj As ListObjects
Dim LastRow As Long

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
Select Case ws.Name
Case Is = "TOC"

Case Else
With ws

‘Insert Table
TableName = "MyTable"
Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection.CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = TableName

'Apply a filter to $ Share for all Brands (Largest to Smallest)
ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ws.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("C3"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending
ws.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ShowAutoFilterDropDown = False

'More Table Formatting Code

End With
End Select
Next ws
End Sub`
```

Update below to reflect Samuel Everson's suggestions:

In my scenario, Sheet1 (TOC) is the WorkSheet I want to skip over.  So, should I write the code this way..?

```
Sub LoopThroughWorkSheets_()

    Dim wb As ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim TableName As String
    Dim LstObj As ListObjects

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Names
    Case Is = "TOC"

    Case Else
        With ws

'Insert Table with the Data starting in Column A, Row 3
    TableName = "MyTable"
    .Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Select
    .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection.CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = TableName

'Apply a filter to C3 (Largest to Smallest)
    .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("C3"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending
    .AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
    .ListObjects("TableName").ShowAutoFilterDropDown = False

'Add a Formula to F4, and Copy Down to Last Row in F (Using Column A as the LastRowData Reference)
    .Range("F4").Formula = "=(E4/(E4-G4))-1"
    .Range("F4").NumberFormat = "0.0%"
    .Range("F4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("F4:F" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

'Update Number Format in Column E & G
    .Columns("E").NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
    .Columns("G").NumberFormat = "$#,##0"


        End With
    End Select
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is that you're not actually using the `With ws`.

Comment: are you sure the worksheet is named `TOC`. No extra space or anything? Also, you can remove `Select Case` and just use `If ws.Name <> "TOC" Then ...` (assuming "TOC" is correct name.)

Comment: @BigBen - that wouldn't cause the code to not execute the `Case Is = "TOC"` though.

Comment: But `Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Select` is problematic @ScottHoltzman, as it will execute on the `ActiveSheet` which is presumably the ToC.

Comment: @BigBen - 100% agree, but it's not the problem the OP is asking about. That will be question two after he solves the first one! (hahaha)

Comment: My guess is this is an X-Y problem... OP thinks the current setup should be the approach to do X (namely skip the TOC sheet), but the actual problem (Y) is the implicit and explicit `ActiveSheet`s.

Comment: @BigBen - good point. I think you are 100% right. You can refactor that code as answer. I am signing off. I am too tired to see the obvious.

Comment: Re your updated code:  you have removed the implicit references to the ActiveSheet, that's good!  But you continue to use Select and Selection, which only work on the ActiveSheet.  You need to remove those, and act on your ranges directly.  Something like `.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange,  .Range("A3").CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = TableName`

Comment: @chrisneilsen if I use: `.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .Range("A3").CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = TableName` then I get a "Compile Error: Invalid or unqualified reference"..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, you're not using your `With ws` statement. I saw this issue arrise in [another one of your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61271852/vba-set-a-loop-for-specific-worksheets-in-a-workbook) earlier in the month too so I thought I'd give an explanation for how to use the statement correctly.

Consider this code:

```
Sub WithStatementExample()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    Range("A1").Value = "This cell is A1 and this sheet name is " & ws.Name
    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value = "This cell is A2 and this sheet name is " & ws.Name
End With

End Sub
```

Now although our statements are encapsulated within the `With` statement, the output to cells `A1` and `A2` will actually both be on whatever sheet is active at the time the code is executed.

As example, consider this new workbook with 3 sheets, all with default names:

[image: New workbook with 3 blank sheets]

If we execute the code based on the workbook in that screenshot, the results will go where we are assuming they will - `Sheet1` cells `A1` and `A2`. But if we run the code whilst `Sheet3` is active, the code outputs the values to  `Sheet3` cells `A1` and `A2`.

[image: Example output of code with Sheet3 selected]

This is because within our `With` statement, we have not used our `ws` worksheet as the object qualifier for the `Range` property.

The range property can apply to both the `Application` and `Worksheet` objects and per [Application.Range documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.Range):

> When used without an object qualifier, this property is a shortcut for ActiveSheet.Range (it returns a range from the active sheet; if the active sheet isn't a worksheet, the property fails).

To get the statements within the `With` block using the *object*, type a `.` in front of your statements:

```
Sub WithStatementExample()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws
    .Range("A1").Value = "This cell is A1 and this sheet name is " & ws.Name
    .Range("A2").Value = "This cell is A2 and this sheet name is " & ws.Name
End With

End Sub
```

Now the output will only go to the sheet assigned to the `ws` variable - in this case, `Sheet1`.

[image: Gif showing all from sheet3 to sheet1, demonstrating where the output is]

If you need some statements to be applied to *other* sheets but executed within your `With` block, you are better off using an explicit reference to the workbook rather than `ActiveSheet` - [This will help explain more - (How to avoid using select in vba)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

So if the `ListObjects` in your code were actually on `Sheets("TOC")` not whichever `ws` the loop is referring to, I'd change `ActiveSheet.ListObjects...` and `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")...` to:

```
wb.Sheets("TOC").ListObjects...
wb.Sheets("TOC").ListObjects("Table1")...
```

---

With your `For Each...Next` loop, your variable `ws` in this case represents an object - specifically a worksheet. The variable `ws` is assigned the next object at each iteration, so you don't need to set the worksheet object to the variable independently to the loop.

In my example above I had 3 sheets. The two below code blocks will achieve the same outcome, one via a `For Each...Next` loop and the other without.

### For Each...Next approach:

```
Sub ForEachExample()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Debug.Print ws.Name
Next ws
End Sub
```

### No loop approach:

```
Sub NoLoopExample()
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)     'The same as Sheets(1) or Sheets("Sheet1")
Debug.Print ws.Name

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)         'The same as Worksheets(2) or Sheets("Sheet2")
Debug.Print ws.Name

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")  'The same as Worksheets(3) or Sheets(3)
Debug.Print ws.Name

End Sub
```

Both of them will output the following to the immediate window in the VBE:

```
Sheet1
Sheet2
Sheet3
```

In your updated code, you are setting `ws` to `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")`.

1. You will need to have a worksheet named `"Sheet2"` in your workbook or you will get a `Runtime Error 9: subscript out of range` error.
2. The next line in your code is the `For Each...Next` statement which will set `ws` to the first sheet in the `Worksheets` collection, regardless of the previous line of code.

What I'm pointing out is that line of code is redundant in your current procedure and depending on the names of your worksheets, will probably be causing a runtime error.

See the [For Each...Next statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement) documentation.

---

With your `Select Case` statement, your first line `Select Case ws.Names` should throw a `Compile Error: Type mismatch`. `ws.Names` returns the collection of worksheet specific names based on the object qualifyer (to it's left) - in this case `ws`. Because we are looking for the sheets name specifically, it should be `ws.Name` which returns the name of the object qualifyer.

- See the [Worksheet.Names documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.names).
- See the [Worksheet.Name documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.name).

So to take that into account it could look something like:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "TOC"
            'Do nothing
        Case Else
            'Do your actions here
    End Select
Next ws
```

As a side note, you could also achieve the same with an `If...Else` statement like so:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "TOC" Then    'Note by using = "TOC" must match exactly, including letter casing. 
        'Do nothing
    Else
        'Do your actions here
    End If
Next ws
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain the `with ws` statement!    I still have a long way to go with understanding object qualifiers and other requirements.  I do try to not use `Select` or ActiveSheet`, but can’t seem to get the code to execute correctly.  Which is probably the issue with the `with ws` statement.    Your explanation did help me better understand the `with ws` statement… However, if I use `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(“Sheet2”), How would the Macro know to loop through to “Sheet3” – “Sheet6”?

Comment: In my scenario, Sheet1 (TOC) is the WorkSheet I want to skip over.  So, should I write the code this way..?
`Sub LoopThroughWorkSheets_()

    Dim wb As ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim TableName As String
    Dim LstObj As ListObjects

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
            
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Names
    Case Is = "TOC"
        
    Case Else
        With ws`

Comment: Updated in OP.  Sorry, I don't know how to insert a comment with the New Code and make it 'Eye Friendly'

Comment: My answer was more general principal in nature about the with statement as the rest of your code looks OK. I'll update my answer to include some information on incorporating the for loop.

Comment: @CariDay I'd added some more info now to the answer about how the `For Each...Loop` works, and an error in the `Select Case`

Comment: This makes a lot of sense!  Yes - the TOC is Sheet1 (TOC)..   With using the `If...Else` statement, the first action `'Insert Table with the Data starting in Column A, Row 3` is stating: Invalid or unqualified reference.  I have: `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "TOC" Then
            'Do Nothing
        Else
        
'Insert Table with the Data starting in Column A, Row 3
    TableName = "MyTable"
    .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A3").CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = "TableName"`

Comment: Should I be adding `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets - If ws.Name = "TOC" Then 'Do Nothing - Else   - With ws`.  That way I'm not worrying about all the `.Range and .Autofilter (s)` showing as Invalid or Unqualified reference?

Comment: He @CariDay. The `With` statement can be before or within your loop. Either way will work fine, It all comes down to where you actually need it. From the looks of things starting it after the `else` statement looks good.

Comment: So I tried all of that, and now I'm getting an `Run-time error '1004': The worksheet data for a table needs to be on the same sheet as the table.`      `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "TOC" Then
            'Do Nothing
        Else
        
            With ws
            
    'Insert Table
        TableName = "MyTable"
        .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A3").CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = TableName`

Comment: @CariDay you should ask a new question regarding your new issue.