# Populate combobox with dynamic list

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, combobox

I'm trying to populate a Combobox with dynamic range.

The code I have is below.

```
cmb_modProp_SA1.List = Array(Worksheets("Properties").Range("B2:B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value)
```

Any tips on how to get this, as the current code only lists the value in B2.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...

```
With Worksheets("Properties")
    cmb_modProp_SA1.List = .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value
End With
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks! I'll have to go through and follow the logic in order to understand it. I've always been weak in the WITH and LOOP areas. I know they're super powerful... but dang, I need help with them.

Comment: @AnthonyRobbins - I answered someone elses question a while back that has an ok explanation of `With...` and `For...` statements. [You can read it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61467329/how-to-loop-through-worksheets-except-toc/61468889#61468889)